# Better segment tree query function for matrix multiplication

Tags: c++, matrix, tree

I have this segtree function to query for a matrix multiplication at a specific range

```cpp
Matrix *Segtree::query(int a, int b, int p, int l, int r) {
  if (b < l || r < a)
    return this->identity_matrix;

  if (a <= l && r <= b)
    return seg[p].matrix;

  int m = (l + r) / 2;

  return Matrix::matrix_mult(query(a, b, 2 * p, l, m),
                             query(a, b, 2 * p + 1, m + 1, r));
}
```

The function works fine and pass in all of the tests, but it gives a memory leak after checking on valgrind because of the matrix_mult function.

```cpp
Matrix *Matrix::matrix_mult(Matrix *a, Matrix *b) {
  Matrix *c = new Matrix(a->rows, b->cols);

  for (int i = 0; i < c->rows * c->cols; i++) {
    c->data[i] = 0;
  }

  matrix_type delimiter = 1e8;

  for (int i = 0; i < a->rows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < b->cols; j++) {
      for (int k = 0; k < a->cols; k++) {
        (*c)(i, j) += (*a)(i, k) * (*b)(k, j);
      }
      (*c)(i, j) %= delimiter;
    }
  }

  return c;
}
```

The matrix mult function creates an C matrix for every call, but i am not deleting it, i want to call a function inside query that makes the matrix multiplication without creating a new one on every iteration.

Comment: Where should the result go, then? I suppose another option would be to pass in a reference to the target matrix, which could then be a local in the calling scope.

Comment: I just need to get the matrix and basically print it with cout before doing another stuff, i'v tried to pass by reference but it did not work

Comment: The first step is to solve the real problem here. This is a fairly common problem called "Pointless Use Of Pointers". Nothing in the shown code requires the use of pointers. C++ code that has a major affliction of pointless use of pointers ends up looking not like C++ code, but like Java or C#. C++ is not Java or C#. Once all the pointless use of pointers is eliminated, once all the pointless pointers are gotten rid off, together with all the `new` and `delete`s, nobody has to worry about deleting anything, anymore. C++ will take care of that, automatically.

Comment: My segments in segtree class has a pointer to matrix class, that is i use pointers

Comment: Unfortunately, the only thing that anyone else on Stackoverflow can possibly know is what's shown in the question. And, based on what's shown in the question, it's just pointless use of pointers.

Comment: Are you bound to use pointers by your assignment? Because it doesn't make any sense in this case if it's for "optimization" since you won't avoid temporary matrices while calculating a multiplication of matrices irrespective of which approach you use to pass them. It won't hurt performance to just return (and store in `Segtree`) `Matrix` by value, especially considering optimizations like NRVO. And even if there were several additional matrix copies, their impact would be negligible compared to multiplication itself and the algorithmical optimizations you get from using the segment tree.

Comment: Yes, i am boud to use pointers

Comment: Is having `this->identity_matrix` as a non-static member of `Segtree` also a requirement? Because if you want your `query` to both use pointers and be practically usable without too much headache, at least the calling site should be sure about whether the returned pointer is semantically owning and has to be `delete`'d. In your case it returns pointer to either the newly-allocated matrix *or* a matrix owned by `Segtree` object (which should be deleted in `Segtree` destructor), which would necessitate the calling code to know implementation details of `query` and use conditional deletion.

Comment: Overall, you want to make sure that your functions have consistent, easy to document behaviour (e.g. `query` should always return a newly allocated and constructed matrix) regarding ownership of returned matrices and take this behaviour into account both in implementation of `Segtree` and in the code that uses it. Then you'll get rid of the memory leaks.

Comment: `this->identiy_matrix` is not a requirement, but i need to pass an identity matrix when i hit the if block. I dont know how i can get rid of memory leaks with this implementation, because i need to return the multiplication matrix, but i also need to delete when i dont use it anymore.

Comment: Thanks guys, i have removed almost all the pointers in my code and now its working fine with no leaks.